# Invalid plugin specification. Invalid "macos" plugin specification. while generating app bundle

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I tried to generate app bundle using flutter command '`flutter build appbundle`' and got this error

Invalid plugin specification.
Invalid "macos" plugin specification.


These are my flutter dependency

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.4+3
  chopper: ^3.0.1
  logging: ^0.11.3+2
  flutter_bloc: ^1.0.0
  built_value: ^6.3.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  dartin: ^0.1.2
  moor_flutter: ^2.0.0
  intl: ^0.16.0
  toast: ^0.1.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.7.1
  chopper_generator: ^3.0.2
  built_value_generator: ^6.3.0
  moor_generator: ^2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message using flutter (after I downgraded my flutter version).
I changed my flutter version to a stable version - check out this link
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

Using this command

```
flutter version v1.9.1+hotfix.6
```

And the issue was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when updated the android SDK and also dart and flutter. After some googling I couldn't find any proper solution so i used the Ancient ways . Heres some solutions which I tried and answered for me. Hope they'll solve your problem too.

1. in android studio open `pubspec.yaml` file and in the top of the window click on flutter Upgrade. Or download and install it from here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows.
   [image]
   after updating flutter the problem should be solved.
2. if you didn't got the answer try to downgrade what you recently updated (including android sdk or flutter sdk).
3. (not recommended) if the issue still consists you can delete everything including flutter, reinstall and changed to the stable channel and it should be fine again.